# Move Fragment left side along with navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I'm new to android.I trying to implement Navigation drawer. I done with that but I want when I click on navigation drawer icon the fragment also move to left as the `ListView` of navigation drawer appears

Answer (score 0):

Try [Jfeinstein10's Sliding menu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)

Comment: Thanks for this cool library. One more question , is that library has a gradle version? Because this is an old project and it is for eclipse version.

Comment: I don't think this project is continued anymore. still you can use this project via https://jitpack.io. But, I would suggest to find something more modern instead of using this one.